# jquery imgareaselect plugin not working

Tags: jquery

i am using the latest version for jquery that is 1.8 and the plugin seem not working in this version.

My whole website is jquery 1.8 compatible and this plugin is not working and since my website is live and its used for main user profile image cropping i really am stuck.

Here is the plugin link https://github.com/odyniec/imgareaselect. if anyone facing same problem and has a solution for it please share it with me.

Comment: It doesn't appear that the plugin has been upgraded to work with jQuery version 1.8.

Comment: yes i have been looking all around the internet for any fork or update if someone has done it . i also mailed the creator of this plugin lets see if he can spare some free time to update this plugin